# Dissecting a proof of the $\Delta$-system lemma

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

I have a question about the following proof of the $\Delta$-system lemma:

[image]

[image]

---

It seems to me that $\mathscr E'$ is not needed. I would start case 1 by "If for every $a \in \bigcup \mathscr E$ the set $\{x \in \mathscr E: a \in x \}$ is countable then ...."

And I'd start the second case by "If there exists an $a \in \bigcup \mathscr E$ such that $\{x \in \mathscr E: a \in x \}$ is uncountable then ...."

My question is: What am I missing? If $\mathscr E' \subseteq \mathscr E$ is needed -- could you explain to me why? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there is an $a\in\bigcup\mathscr{E}$ such that $\{x\in\mathscr{E}:a\in x\}$ is uncountable, $\{x\in\mathscr{E}:|x|=1\}$ is countable, and $\mathscr{E}'=\{x\in\mathscr{E}:|x|=2\}$ is uncountable, so you want to use the argument in the induction step. Doing it your way it may happen that for each $a\in\bigcup\mathscr{E}'$ the set $\{x\in\mathscr{E}':a\in x\}$ is countable. In that case each possible choice of $\mathscr{E}_a'$ is only countable, and you can’t apply the induction hypothesis. In order to be sure that you can always carry out the induction, you need to know that **every** uncountable $\mathscr{E}'\subseteq\mathscr{E}$ covers some $a\in\bigcup\mathscr{E}'$ uncountably often.

Comment: Questions used to be bounced on accept. Has this feature been removed?

Comment: @Matt: I’m not following: *bounced*?

Comment: I meant moved to the front page. Like it does when you edit something.

Comment: @Matt: Are you looking at the Active front page, or the Questions front page? (I always look at the latter, so I never see that sort of thing anyway.)

Comment: I visit the plain SE url which seems to be taking me to the active tab ("active" comes with an underline). Then this seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Matt: Or a changed policy?

Comment: Yeah, or that. ${}$

Comment: But dropping $\mathscr E'$ in case 1 works, right? Surely we can construct the desired family if all $a \in \bigcup \mathscr E$ are only in countably many sets.

Comment: @Matt: You need Case 2 exactly as it is, and Case 1 is its negation, so you need Case 1 as is. It’s true that if $\mathscr{E}$ is ‘nice’, we can use it as our $\mathscr{E}'$, but if it’s not ‘nice’, we still may not be in Case 2.

Comment: Yes! (Been thinking the argument through and understand it now) Thank you : ) (btw, have you considered going for moderator?)

Comment: @Matt: You’re welcome. (I’ve not absolutely ruled it out, but I *really* don’t want to do it.)